# NSE in nested function calls

Tags: r, tidyeval, nse

I'd like to use a utility function to check whether a given column exists within a given `data.frame`.  I'm piping within the tidyverse.  The best I've come up with so far is

```
library(magrittr)

columnExists <- function(data, col) {
  tryCatch({
    rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(col)) %in% names(data)
    },
    error=function(e) FALSE
  )
}
```

This works in the global environment

```
> mtcars %>% columnExists(mpg)
[1] TRUE
> mtcars %>% columnExists(bad)
[1] FALSE
```

But not when called from within another function, which is my actual use case

```
outerFunction <- function(d, col) {
  d %>% columnExists((col))
}
> mtcars %>% outerFunction(mpg)  # Expected TRUE
[1] FALSE
> mtcars %>% outerFunction(bad) # Expected FALSE
[1] FALSE
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible to have a single function that works correctly in the global environment and also when nested in another function?

I have found several SO posts related to checking for the existence of a given column or columns, but they all seem to assume either that the column name will be passed as a string or the call to check existence is not nested (or both).  That is not the case here.

Comment: Incidentally, what's the purpose of the `tryCatch`? I would remove that, it will silently produce the wrong result in case the user passes a bogus argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Similar to my comment to MrFlick, in an earlier iteration it was necessary to prevent an error when the function was passed a non-existent column.  But you're correct: it's not necessary with this version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to pass though the original symbol in your outerFunction. Use

```
outerFunction <- function(d, col) {
  d %>% columnExists( {{col}} )
}
```

The "embrace" syntax will prevent early evaluation.

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that!  But I went through so many conbinations of that and various others, it looks like I missed the obvious.  Thank you.

Comment: @MrFlick. You mean:  `col` will be early evaluated by `enquo()`?!

Comment: @TarJae. More like `enquo` will just see `col`, rather than the value that's passed to `col`. So i'm not really using "evaluation" here correctly but I'm not sure what I could call it.